# Non-type template parameters pointer to object

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

Please I want complete example of how to use Non-type template parameters pointer to object, I tried this code but it contains alot of errors

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo()
        {

        }
};

template<typename T,Foo* foo>
class TFoo
{
public:
    TFoo()
    {

    }
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    TFoo<float,&foo> tfoo;
}
```

Comment: Local (non-static) variables doesn't really have a fixed place in memory at time of compilation, which means a pointer to a local variable (like `foo`  in your example) is not a compile-time constant expression which is needed to instantiate a template.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , thank you I just want to know what the following code in the standard n1905 means: 
`template < class T , char * p > 
class X 
{
//***
X();
X( const char * q ) 
{ 
/**/ 
}
};
X<int ," Studebaker " > x1 ; // error: string literal as template-argument
char p [] = " Vivisectionist ";
X<int ,p > x2 ; // OK`

Comment: That example code declares all variables as *global* variables, and global variables are put into a specific place and location at the time of the compilation and can therefore be used as template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Template parameters are to be evaluated in compile-time to instantiate a template, but the value of `&foo` is known only in run-time. That is your problem.

Probably, you should use different architecture. May be you could pass `Foo*` as a non-template parameter to your constructor. (I can't even imagine a purpose, for which a pointer as a template parameter could be useful).